# Real-time Antivirus in Ubuntu

Tags: anti-virus

I need to find a real-time security solution for Ubuntu. I already tried ClamAV (with ClamTK), Bitdefender Scanner for Unices, and Avast4Linux Workstation, but they all are only scanners, and they don't have automatic scanning by default. Is there a certain product (or certain products) that provide real-time protection to your system (so it's not just a scanner like ClamAV)?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware): *The following is a partial list of known Linux malware. However, few if any are in the wild, and most have been rendered obsolete by Linux updates or were never a threat. Known malware is not the only or even the most important threat: new malware or attacks directed to specific sites can use vulnerabilities previously unknown to the community or unused by malware.* In other words, you don't need real-time protection on Linux. Instead, you need real-time updates.

Comment: I'm just asking _if_ there is some software that has real-time protection.

Comment: Product recommendations are [off-topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), sorry.

Comment: By the way, why would you run real-time scanner if you don't need it? Installing unnecessary tools that significantly affect performance isn't fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ESET Linux Antivirus 4 for Desktop works on Ubuntu 12.10 and later. This antivirus product; however, costs money. You can use any ESET license key (username and password) that works on the PC or Mac for this product as well. Another more known product is COMODO antivirus for Linux. It only works on Ubuntu 12.04, because it needs to install kernels that can only function on that version. These products should also have automatic updating as well.

You can also configure automatic scanning for some products such as ClamAV (including ClamTK), if that's all you want.

(Antivirus in Linux is not really needed, though)

Answer (score 1):

The vast amount of Linux distributions, paired with it's low presence as an OS (most people in the world either use Windows or OSX in their PC's) and it's constant updates, make it not worthwhile to develop malware or viruses aimed at that platform. As such, the concept of a real-time antivirus suite, in Linux, is not worthwhile.

I do remember seeing some antivirus suites designed for Linux (as to scan for files being transfered to Windows), but it is nothing a simple Google search might answer.

[This set of guidelines](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus), made by the Ubuntu folks, explicit most of what I say. You only need an antivirus to prevent spreading infected files to *infectable* platforms.