# Unetbootin stops at 0% extracting bootloader configuration

Tags: unetbootin

I'm running debian 7 stable release with unetbootin 575-1

If I run 'sudo unetbootin' and select my ISO image (boot-rescue-32bit.iso) and select my newly formatted USB drive click ok, then unetbootin gets stuck on Extracting and Copying Files at 0%.

I've tried the latest unetbootin 608 version as well, same problem.

I've also tried a different ISO, still no joy. Both of the ISO files I know work as I've burnt them to CD and booted them on a computer.[image]

I've also tried a different USB flash drive and a different USB slot (on-board instead of through a USB hub)

Answer (score 2):

Be patient :) The file is unpacking and seems to take a while.
I had the same problem and in the time it took me to find and read through all the comments on this page, 0.hfs was unpacked and the installation continued!

Comment: yep, good advice. Particuarly need to be patient when the file size (on the right side of the "source" row is large (e.g. > 500mb)

Answer (score 0):

Do these ISOs contain a distribution that UNetbootin normally supports? The Unetbootin site says:

> UNetbootin doesn't use distribution-specific rules for making your
>   live USB drive, so most Linux ISO files should load correctly using
>   this option. However, not all distributions support booting from USB,
>   and some others require extra boot options or other modifications
>   before they can boot from USB drives, so these ISO files will not work
>   as-is. Also, ISO files for non-Linux operating systems have a
>   different boot mechanism, so don't expect them to work either.

Comment: Yes I have managed to use those same ISO files on another machine and used unetbootin successfully to create my USB drives. So it's just something on the debian 7 box which I need to get working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this translates to Linux (I'm sure it's somehow applicable, I'm just not sure how it translates exactly), but I was having the same problem on Mac, and I believe it was because of how I'd formatted my USB stick.  Originally I had just created a partition as FAT and was able to load many different ISOs onto the device.  Then I made a mistake and had to re-format(?) the whole device, which included re-making the file/partition table.  Originally I just chose the default "Scheme", "GUID Partition Map".  From this point on I was having trouble.  I had a hunch that it might require the "Master Boot Record" scheme, so I erased the whole USB stick again with that setting.  Then when I ran unetbootin again it worked without issue.

So maybe try recreating the entire partition table on the USB first and see if that helps.

[Example of Erase settings in Mac Disk Utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLcU7.png)

Answer (score -2):

check your antivirus software
i oonce had this issue, it was blocking an autorun file

Comment: My virus scan ClamTK only runs at night on a schedule, not in the background

Comment: Try [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/). you may need wine

Comment: Installing Wine to run a program for such a trivial task is ridiculous. So is expecting Linux user to have a real-time antivirus.

Comment: I believe the user already has wine installed

Comment: I have a real time antivirus...and no i use windows

Comment: That's the thing. You're using Windows which is malware's main target. It's madness to run Windows without real-time protection. Linux is a different story. It's designed with security in mind and not so popular, so there are less people willing to create Linux malware. Actually it's already hardened against most threats. It's secured against them directly in the OS (or packages, which are auto-updated and much more secure than in Windows). You'd rather be hit by a lightning than by Linux malware. [Related question](http://superuser.com/q/694285/194694)